# How can a Dragon Zombie be killed?

Tags: dragons, zombies, tactics

SETTING: You live on a planet inhabited by intelligent dragons with the physical characteristics of a fire-breathing Smaug-type dragon. They are not above only partially burning their victims before consuming them. Like the French, they like their meat bloody!

Adults dragons live in small groups, in isolated pockets. They lay several eggs in each clutch, hatching dragonets of the size of horses. Only one or two dragonets making it to full adulthood from each batch. Once matured, the young dragons leave the nest and join up with other zit-faced dragons forming larger social groups until their youthful exuberance amongst themselves has whittled down the young group size to their adult social group setting.

They have above human intelligence, excellent hearing, and incredibly tough scales, plate armor, muscles to get through if you intended on trying to kill them. They release pent up gases and heat as a steady stream of fire.

Mercifully, they normally stay out of the way of humans, and allow normal life to continue. So they have never really been a threat before, as long as you kept out of their way and didn’t mind a few cattle going missing every now and then.

SCENARIO: Your planet experiences the zombie apocalypse. Mercifully, you find out that ALL the ancient fables on how to kill a zombie are correct.

The virus affects the infected intelligence regions, making them 'dumber' but not completely stupid. The smarter you were before you were infected, the 'smarter' you are as a zombie. This allows for some really stupid Zombies and some not so stupid Zombies.

The virus also affects the infected individuals speed and co-ordination so that you get the slow shuffling type of zombie (the thought of a smart, fast moving zombie is just too scary to contemplate, so I'm sticking to slow and shuffling).

The Zombies lose any interest in things that interested them before and being attracted by sound are prone to forming vast zombie hordes (a zombie shuffling along is not the quietest thing in the world).

The virus is transmitted by infected blood mixing with uninfected blood. So just getting blood on you is not a death sentence. This also means that eating uncooked flesh or partially uncooked flesh transmits the virus and it has spread to the rest of the animal kingdom.

Eventually the top apex predators are infected. You find out the cure is in the dragon's [insert ‘body part that is hard to get to’ here]. Unfortunately, the dragons have now become infected. And any that aren’t infected, aren’t willing to give up their lives so that you can live. Besides, any dragons not infected are smart enough to flee to some extremely isolated spot and QUIETLY wait the apocalypse out. Time for a good snooze!

ASSUMPTION: There are human survivors, somehow.

QUESTION: How would you go about killing a Dragon Zombie?

With the cure in the [insert 'body part that is hard to get to' here], you can't just ignore the dragons and hope they don't come after you.

Taking into account it's MASSIVE SIZE, scales, thick skull etc. It can no longer breathe a steady stream of fire at you, but has to release the buildup of heat somehow and seems to hiccup a fireball every now and then.

Starting from an above human intelligence, an average dragon zombie is now about as smart as the average human. With a loss of coordination, it is as likely to crush you by accident as to try and get to your brains.

It has lost the ability to fly (with intentional takeoff, wing-flapping, and precision landing), but can climb with some effort. If pushed off the edge of a cliff, it could have sufficient time and brainpower to open their wings to manage a sort of glide and not crash to their deaths!

**EDIT:** the Zombies are of the slow shuffling 'Walking Dead' kind and not the energiser bunny 'World War Z' type!

**FURTHER EDITs** to improve Dragon population numbers, dragon description, zombie description, dragon zombie description.

Comment: I think this is quite the broad topic.  There are a vast number of dragon archetypes, each which have different weaknesses and strengths.  There are a vast number of zombie archetypes, each of which have their own weaknesses and strengths.  Multiply those together, and you have an extraordinary number of potential answers, each of which depends almost entirely on information not part of the original question.

Comment: I did try to limit it to Tolkien's Smaug-type dragon and slow shuffling 'Walking Dead' Type Zombies.

Comment: Isn't the answer simply however you say they can be killed? Smaug was only slain because 1) he was an idiot and 2) the plot called for it.

Comment: Could a zombie Dragon of the stupid variety fly?  Could it climb?  My wager would be no as flight takes a lot of non-shambling control...not quite so sure on climb as it could be done as raw strength.  A large pit, some bait, and a large boulder to drop on it after it entered would suffice.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps How do you reconcile the the LOTR world with the Walking Dead one?  Like, if the dragons are LOTR dragons then they are non-free-willed slaves of Melkor (as are, presumably, the zombies).  This would seem to indicate that there is no difference between a zombie dragon and a regular dragon except perhaps in what happens to people they bite.  Regardless, if they are LOTR dragons, the correct answer is 'pray and behave as directed by the will of God'.  You see how this is a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that all the ancient fables also correlate to zombies being dumb and shambling husks of their former selves.

With this in mind, I would place some tempting (and hopefully noisy) bait in a cage directly above a ballista. As the zombie dragon shuffles forward... Bam! Headshot with a large bolt of wood and metal.

Comment: Assumption correct but I haven't yet decided if they can still breath fire properly or at least cough up a firebolt. Also, I believe their thick skulls would withstand a measly wooden bolt. an iron bolt might be a different story.

Comment: Or, along similar lines, put the bait on the other side of a giant guillotine. Zombie dragon goes for the bait and whamo. As above, this assumes the stereotypical slow, shambling and, above all, stupid zombies. The live dragon would never fall for such an obvious trap but the zombie dragon would. Same reason zombie humans do stupid things and mostly just get by on numbers and being hard to kill.

Comment: (Come to think of it, "zombie dragons" of the dumb type actually isn't a great idea because there wouldn't be a lot of them. Slow, shambling, dumb zombies are only scary because there are so many of them. If there's only like 1 of them, you could pretty much just walk away from it.)

Comment: @JamieB Good point about the numbers. I hadn't intended on there only being one. but also didn't intend for there to be thousands of dragon zombies in one spot. I'll make an edit to clarify.